# New line in ssrs expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an expression that suppose to be in one line. But the the number is jumping into another line in the textbox. What can I do to make it in one line.
The output is giving

```
2018-06-26HP-HPP
4
```

Code :

```
=Trim(Format(CDate(Fields!Startdate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) & Trim(Fields!Register.Value) & Trim(DatePart(DateInterval.Hour,  Fields!GSTIME.Value)).ToString()
```

Expected answer should be :

```
2018-06-26HP-HPP4
```

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Your text box length is smaller then text. So might be text goes into next line.

Comment: I have expanded it already.

Comment: Is there a hidden new line character in the field `Register.Value`?

Comment: @Mazhar I am not sure why the field is having new line. There is no new line in the filed Regsiter.value. I need to get it right before I use it in lookup.

Comment: @great77 - see my explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your expected result

`2018-06-26HP-HPP4`

from

```
=Trim(Format(CDate(Fields!Startdate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) & Trim(Fields!Register.Value) & Trim(DatePart(DateInterval.Hour,  Fields!GSTIME.Value)).ToString()
```

but you're getting this

```
2018-06-26HP-HPP
4
```

And the text box is large enough to show this on one line then I suspect you have a new line character in the field `Fields!Register.Value`

because

the first part of the expected result (`2018-06-26`) comes from

`Trim(Format(CDate(Fields!Startdate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"))`

The second part (`HP-HPP`) comes from this

`Trim(Fields!Register.Value)`

The final part (4) comes from this

`Trim(DatePart(DateInterval.Hour,  Fields!GSTIME.Value)).ToString()`

The new line you're seeing in the text box is between the 2nd and 3rd parts which I suspect may be in the contents of `Trim(Fields!Register.Value)`

If this field is in a db table then when you select the column search and replace for hidden carriage returns, line feeds and tabs.

Here's one way

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (tmp NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tmp (tmp)
SELECT 'Help' + CHAR(10) + 'me' + CHAR(9) + 'please' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT tmp FROM @tmp )
PRINT @val
```

output

```
Help
me  please
```

remove the hidden characters

```
SET @val = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(tmp,' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ') FROM @tmp )
PRINT @val
```

output

`Help me please`

Comment: I could not find the new line. How will I find it?

Comment: Is the data coming from a database table? Then query the column for char(13) which is carriage return and/or char(10) which is line feed

Comment: You are right. When I removed the Register Table. everything comes back to oneline. The database is SQL table. Can I not use expression to do that in ssrs, how would I do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have accepted your answer though I used the expression to remove the carriage return as   REPLACE(Fields!REGISTER.Value, vbCrLF, ""). Many thanks